# Can I play the game without the disc by installing disc 2 to HDD?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

Is is possible to download the story mode of the GTA V game (disk 2)?

I know people say not to, but my brother has the game, and he wants the disk, so I was wondering if it is possible to actually install it and play in, without the disk in. So it's his game, but I can just install onto my Xbox and he can keep the disks, so we can both play the game.

If it is possible, can you please give me instructions on how to download it. Thank you.

Comment: It's generally not possible to play Xbox 360 games without the disk.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the situation here. You both have a 360, and if I understand correctly (which doesn't appear to be the case) you have a disc **and** a download version, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Nolonar No he wants to install the play disc to his hard drive and play it without the disc. Which is not possible and goes into that ever so scary piracy area.

Comment: Trying to do what you want is borderline piracy, which is something that we don't support.  If you want to play the same game on two consoles at the same time, you need two licenses, which means paying for two copies.

Comment: @MBraedley Not so sure on the borderline unless because you purchased one copy it becomes borderline...

Comment: @ColeBusby It's borderline because there's nothing wrong until you try and use the same license in two places at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

Installing a game from the disc to the hard drive does not mean that you can play the game without the disc being in the machine, it simply reduces the amount of data that will be read from the disc during play.

To install the second disc, select "Options" when viewing the disc in the "My Games" section of the dashboard, then select "Install to Hard Drive". This is not recommended, but certainly possible -- though it won't do what you apparently want it to.

GTA 5 is not currently available for download purchase on Xbox Live, and no release date for this has been announced that I can see.

Comment: Would doing that improve load times?  What about installing to a USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

To have more than 1 copy, you need to purchase the game with your credit card and install it on the first Xbox, then sign in with the same account you purchased with on xbox two, then download it and sign in your account and play. This method is 100% legal.

Answer (score -2):

For games, get them of the xbox store and license transfer them.

Comment: Can you detail on the 'license transfer' part?